How to ensure countdown timer updates the page title even when the tab is inactive?
Google's countdown timer effectively updates the time in the browser tab's title, even when users navigate to other tabs. This seamless functionality relies on efficient background execution to keep the countdown active. I’m working on implementing a similar feature but facing an issue: the title stops updating or lags when the user leaves the tab.
To address this, I tried several approaches, including Web Workers, WebSockets, and requestAnimationFrame. Unfortunately, none fully resolved the issue because browsers tend to throttle background processes in inactive tabs to optimize resource usage, especially for battery life on mobile devices.
Here’s an example of what I attempted using requestAnimationFrame:
let countdown = 60; // Countdown duration in seconds

function updateTitle() {
    if (countdown > 0) {
        document.title = `Time Left: ${countdown}s`;
        countdown--;
        requestAnimationFrame(updateTitle);
    } else {
        document.title = "Time's up!";
    }
}

updateTitle();

While this works well in an active tab, the browser throttles requestAnimationFrame when the tab is inactive, causing the timer to freeze or lag. Using setInterval faces a similar challenge, as it's also throttled in inactive tabs.
To tackle this, I explored Web Workers, which can run JavaScript in the background without being affected by the browser's main thread. Here’s a simplified example:
Worker Script (timerWorker.js):
let countdown = 60;
setInterval(() => {
    if (countdown > 0) {
        postMessage(countdown--);
    }
}, 1000);

Main Script:
const worker = new Worker('timerWorker.js');

worker.onmessage = function (e) {
    document.title = `Time Left: ${e.data}s`;
};

worker.postMessage('start');

While Web Workers help decouple processes, they do not update the DOM directly and can still encounter throttling in some scenarios. The Web Worker approach works for a longer period before it's stops updating. Thanks for your help in advance.

countdown-- doesn't make much sense, when you can't guarantee the code will execute every second. You should rather work with a Date instance, and get the difference between the current time, and the time when you initialized the whole thing. That might of course not get you an updated display every single second either - but at least the timer will be correct, when it finally updates.

You’re absolutely right that relying on countdown-- isn’t reliable, especially when the execution intervals can be inconsistent due to throttling. Using a Date instance is a better approach since it calculates the time difference between the start time and the current time, ensuring the timer remains accurate. However, even with this approach, the issue persists in inactive tabs because the browser delays or pauses the rendering of updates in background tabs. The main code uses Date instance and not countdown--

One comment mentioned that we need to use absolute time to calculate the time (Date.now()). In addition to that we also need setInterval to keep updating the title regardless of the tab's visibility. Here is the code based on what you provided, hope this is helpful!
const countdownDuration = 60;
const endTime = Date.now() + countdownDuration * 1000;

function formatTime(seconds) {
    const mins = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    const secs = seconds % 60;
    return `${mins}:${secs < 10 ? '0' : ''}${secs}`;
}

function updateTitle() {
    const now = Date.now();
    const remaining = Math.max(0, Math.floor((endTime - now) / 1000));

    if (remaining > 0) {
        document.title = `Time Left: ${formatTime(remaining)}`;
    } else {
        document.title = "Time's up!";
        clearInterval(timerInterval);
    }
}

updateTitle();

setInterval(updateTitle, 1000);


Thank you for your contribution. However, the underlying issue is related to how browsers manage resource usage when a tab becomes inactive. When you navigate away from a tab, browsers often throttle or pause JavaScript execution for timers like setInterval to conserve resources. This behavior can cause the countdown to desynchronize or stop updating until the tab becomes active again. As a result, the code you've provided might not fully resolve the problem.

@IwalewaFawaz Hi, I tested it on my Chrome and it worked when the tab was inactive. Could you provide more info about the env you're using if it doesn't work?

The browser takes time to throttle or pause JavaScript execution. You can test the behavior by setting a timer for 20 minutes or longer. In my tests, I used a 10-minute timer to observe the execution of the script in both Chrome and Microsoft Edge.
In Chrome, the timer stopped at 4 minutes and 21 seconds before resuming, skipping a few seconds. On the other hand, Microsoft Edge paused the timer at exactly 4 minutes and 12 seconds, and it did not resume the countdown.
